# can't use copyTo to copy a rectangular matrix into a 3D matrix

Tags: opencv, matrix

I have 5rows x 4cols cv::Mat:

```
int output_size[] = {5,4};
cv::Mat im1(2, output_size, CV_32FC1);

float* ptr = (float*)im1.data;

for (unsigned int r = 0; r < output_size[0]; r++) {
  for (unsigned int c = 0; c < output_size[1]; c++) {
    *ptr = (r*im1.size.p[1])+c;
    std::cout << *ptr++ << ",";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

So that matrix looks like this:

```
[ 0,  1,  2,  3,
  4,  5,  6,  7,
  8,  9, 10, 11,
 12, 13, 14, 15,
 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Furthermore, I have another 3depth x 5rows x 4cols cv::Mat:

```
int output_size2[] = {3,5,4};
cv::Mat im2(3, output_size2, CV_32FC1);
im2 = 0;
```

Now I want to copy im1 into, let's say, the second layer of im2. I do the following:

```
cv::Range rngs[] = {cv::Range(1,2), cv::Range::all(), cv::Range::all()};
cv::Mat dst = im2(rngs);
im1.copyTo(dst);
```

This doesn't seem to work. im1.copyTo(dst) has no effect on im2 - all the second layer values remain zero after the operation. After some introspection, it seems like opencv is finding that since the size of dst is 1x5x4 and not 5x4, it reassigns dst.

What would be the right way to copy a rectangular matrix into one layer of a 3D matrix?

---

Ok this works:

```
void* ptr = im2.data + im2.step[0]*1;
memcpy(ptr, (void*)im1.data, im1.total()*sizeof(float));
```

but is there an "opencv" way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have n 2-dim images and you want to use them as layers in a 3D matrix that has a third dimension of size n you can use `cv::merge`. see [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=merge#merge).

See also:

`cv:split` [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=split#cv-split)